# Keycloak: Update custom user attribute from "Edit Account"-page

Tags: keycloak

when I add a custom attribute to a user, I can access this programmatically in my client application using custom mappers. But when a user logs into its account settings (URL /auth/realms//account/), he or she does not see or update this attribute. Only the required ones first and last name and email are visible.

How can I make a custom attribute visible and updateable on the account page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create custom theme and override `account.ftl` template to add custom attributes.

Read through [Theme Creation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes), it's really easy to create custom theme.

Comment: Hi, document only says how to display the attributes under account management. But how do we add validation logic similar to custom validation form-action for registration? Moreover, if some attributes required values to be selected from a drop-down, how to do that? Please answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634584/keycloak-custom-attrbiutes-validation-on-edit