# Keycloak custom attrbiutes validation on edit

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, customization, account

I have added few custom attributes for my org's requirement to registration field. Have customized the theme and added validation as per the documentation. It works fine. I could add these attributes to account management page also by modifying the account template.

However, I want to add capability to edit these custom attributes under account management as well as custom validation logic for this edit action. I can't get any reference to the documentation.

Would appreciate any help. I am using Keycloak 12.0.2 on RHEL 7.9 OS with Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering it after long time, but newer version of Keycloak from 14.0 onwards, they have something called `declarative user profile` which can be enabled to have custom attributes. It allows to define custom attributes from admin console. One can configure permissions for admin and the user, additionally one can configure to use inbuilt basic validators. Keycloak renders registration form and update profile form dynamically based on these attributes. However, as far as I know, as of version 18.0.2, you still need to modify account template for allowing custom attributes visible and modifiable from account management. Same validators works with just modification of template, you need not do anything in code. I am referring to Keycloak WildFly distribution, which is rechristened as legacy distribution now.

Here are the links the same -

1. [Github User Profile](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/user-profile.md)
2. [Redhat issue or umbrella task for related work](https://issues.redhat.com/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20KEYCLOAK%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22user%20profile%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC)
3. [Keycloak documentation - Defining User Profile](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#defining-a-user-profile)

Answer (score 0):

I know three options for this.

- You can overwrite your Keycloak source code according to your needs but i did not suggest that because of if you update source code , Using new version of keycloak will be harder.
- You can relocated your custom validations on your modifying the account template.
- You can write completely new interface ,which is not using directly keycloak, and you can write new backend which is using admin rest api on keycloak.By the way you can find adaptors for keycloak admin api's for different languages(For Js : [keycloak-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-admin))

Comment: I have already added the custom attributes to my registration page, I could also validate them by implementing FormAction and FormActionFactory interfaces. I could also get these attributes displayed under account management by modifying the account.ftl template. My question is I don't know a way to validate these custom attributes when a user edits and save them via account management. Is there any SPI for this which i can implement and write validation logic?

Comment: 4) You can write custom REST SPI (`RealmResourceProviderFactory` + `RealmResourceProvider`) for update user attributes